# How to wrap panel output in IntelliJ 9?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, word-wrap

I recently converted to IntelliJ, love it.

How do I get panels, such as log output, IDETalk, etc. to wrap their contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soft wrapping for Editor and Console has been implemented in IDEA 10 (<s>which is not released yet</s>). It's not possible in IDEA 9, sorry.

Comment: Bummer. Thank you for answering my question though!

Answer (score 20):

IntelliJ is now at version 2016 and in this version at least wrapping is supported.

It is the squiggly line icon that is selected in this image:

[image: It is the squiggly line icon selected here]