# How can I force IntelliJ to wrap a very long line in a *.txt file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I made a program that saves in a *.txt file the factorial of a number. It is possible to wrap the content of a line to fit in the visible area of the screen?

IntelliJ:
[image]

Notepad:
[image]

Comment: see answer #1:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004520/code-wrap-intellij

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that question. Should I delete mine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code Wrap IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004520/code-wrap-intellij)

Comment: I think `Soft Wrap` (as referenced in the question linked above) will only work if there are spaces in the string i.e. some point at which the wrap can be engaged.

Comment: Yeah! You're right. Didn't work for me! My question isn't about code wrapping in the editor ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 1. Open setting either by selecting File -> Settings or (Ctrl + Alt +
    s). 
 2. Navigate to Editor -> General 
 3. You should find an option '**Soft-Wrap these files**', add the desired file formats and apply the changes.
```

This should solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No solution is viable (except a text editor with line wrap, but you've stated that's not what you're seeking), as the potential line breaks depend on a specific user's screen resolution, set text size etc.

You could read the screen resolution and make some assumptions with that information, but I would advise against it.

Comment: Wrong. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094223/how-to-wrap-panel-output-in-intellij-9